# why do I get a single field value in Django formset_factory?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

when I checked formset_factory validation and get fields to value from formset it returns only one field value from formset. But I can not find any problem in my code. please help me to solve the problem.

My form.py:

```
class SbTitleForm(forms.Form):
    sb_title = forms.CharField(required=False)
    sb_permission = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

SbTitleFormSet = formset_factory(SbTitleForm, extra=0)
```

My view.py:

```
def menuuser(request):
    sbtitle = SbTitle.objects.all().values()
    sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(initial=sbtitle)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sbtitle_form = SbTitleForm(request.POST, initial=sbtitle)
        if sbtitle_form.is_valid():
            print(sbtitle_form.cleaned_data)
            
    context = {
        'sbtitle_form':sbtitle_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'admins/user_role/user_permission.html', context)
```

My HTML:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %} 
{% load static %} 
{% block content %}
<div class="card">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ sbtitle_form.management_form }}
    {{ sbitleelement_form.management_form }}
    <div id="DataTables_Table_2_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
        <div class="datatable-scroll">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover datatable-highlight dataTable no-footer" id="DataTables_Table_2" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_2_info">
                <thead>
                    <tr role="row" class="bg-teal-400">
                        <th class="sorting text-center h5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Job Title: activate to sort column ascending">Sidebar Title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for field in sbtitle_form %}
                    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                        <td class="sorting_1 text-center"><h4>{{ field.sb_title.value }} {{ field.sb_permission }}<p class="text-danger">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</p></h4></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

when I try to **print(sbtitle_form.cleaned_data)** its return only one field value like as **`{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}`**. I can not get other field value in formset. please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: `sbtitle_form = SbTitleForm(request.POST, initial=sbtitle)` shoud be `sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(request.POST, initial=sbtitle)`

Answer (score 1):

`sbtitle_form = SbTitleForm(request.POST, initial=sbtitle)`

shoud be:

`sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(request.POST, initial=sbtitle)`

```
def menuuser(request):
    sbtitle = SbTitle.objects.all().values()
    sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(initial=sbtitle)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(request.POST, initial=sbtitle) # <----
        if sbtitle_form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
    context = {
        'sbtitle_form':sbtitle_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'admins/user_role/user_permission.html', context)
```

If you want to access to each of forms:

```
def menuuser(request):
    sbtitle = SbTitle.objects.all().values()
    sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(initial=sbtitle)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sbtitle_form = SbTitleFormSet(request.POST, initial=sbtitle)
        if sbtitle_form.is_valid():
            for form in sbtitle_form.forms:  # <----
                print(form.cleaned_data)
    context = {
        'sbtitle_form':sbtitle_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'admins/user_role/user_permission.html', context)
```

Comment: I have another problem that occurs now. when I do click the submit button the **{% for field in sbtitle_form %}** loop continues an extra 5 in the HTML template and the result like as **{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': True}
{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}
{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}
{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}
{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}
{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}
{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}
{'sb_title': '', 'sb_permission': False}**. why do it?